# Need to summarize and count a group of common records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by, distinct

Basically, I have a cut optimizer that outputs a list of "cuts" by "extrusion" and "cut length". My main goal is to cut this down to a summarized cut sheet.  Below is a few lines for show, but one scenario I have ends up with 1000+ cuts. There end up being a lot of "Extrusions" with the same set of "cuts" on each of them.

```
    Cut_ID | Ext_ID | CutLength
      1         1         139
      2         1         139
      3         2         139
      4         2         139
      5         3         139
      6         3         130
      7         4         285
```

What I'm trying to do, is identify and group all similar "extrusions" as a "group" with a corresponding "qty" ...like this:

```
    ExtGroup | Qty 
        1       2      
        2       1      
        3       1
```

Afterwards, I'll put everything into a corresponding table that shows what cut lengths need to be on each of these "groups"

```
    ExtGroup | CutLength 
        1         139
        1         139
        2         139
        2         130
        3         265
```

Let me know if I should be approaching this problem from a different angle.....I need to end up making a simple report/graphic for people to print rut and put on a clipboard to reference while cutting extrusions

thanks

Edit: Changed some terminology and tried to clear up some stuff that was a little obscure. Stock_ID is now referred to as Ext_ID...which represents a single extrusion

Comment: What is Piece_Id supposed to be? Is it the Stock_Id?

Comment: sorry,it is not clear to me.Explain the output,you are looking.Explain once again to get better response.

Comment: Stock_ID is what I use to refer to a specific extrusion that needs to be cut. That stock_id has one or more cuts (cut_id) in it of a certain length. Since there may be a lot of extrusions with the exact same cuts in them, I am trying to group identical "stock_ids" into a single "piece_id" with a corresponding quantity.

Comment: I edited the original question to make more sense

Answer (score 0):

This is a pain in SQL Server.  I think the easiest method is just to use aggregate string concatenation to define the pieces.

You *can* do this in SQL Server:

```
select row_number() over (select NULL)) as pieceId,
       count(*) as numstocks
from (select stockid,
             stuff((select ',' + cast(cutlength as varchar(255))
                    from t t2
                    where t2.stockid = t.stockid
                    for xml path ('')
                   ), 1, 1, '') as cuts
      from t
      group by stockid
     ) s
group by cuts;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called Normalising. The purpose is to reduce redundant information in the database, which makes it easier to maintain. Generally, this is a good thing to do, so you are on the right track.

In data warehouses the opposite approach of Denormalising is commonly used, however that is not applicable in this case.

You can read more about it here: Wikipedia > Database normalization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

If you want to learn about it in depth, Chris Date is the leading guru. He has published a number of books including: Database Design and Relational Theory, published by O'Reilly Media. However his books are somewhat heavy going and overkill for this case.

You could create separate tables for Size and Stock like this.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Size
(
    SizeID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CutLength int NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Stock
(
    StockID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Description] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    SizeID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Size(SizeID),
    Quantity int NOT NULL
);
```

Then insert some values into the tables.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Size (SizeID, CutLength)
    VALUES
    (1, 139),
    (2, 139),
    (3, 285);

INSERT INTO dbo.Stock (StockID, [Description], SizeID, Quantity)
    VALUES
    (101, N'Plastic', 1, 10),
    (102, N'Metal', 1, 25),
    (103, N'Plastic', 2, 15),
    (104, N'Metal', 2, 75),
    (105, N'Plastic', 3, 12);
```

When you want to report, you can "join" the two tables like this.

```
SELECT S.StockID, S.[Description], S.SizeID, Z.CutLength, S.Quantity
    FROM dbo.Stock AS S
        INNER JOIN dbo.Size AS Z
            ON Z.SizeID = S.SizeID
    ORDER BY StockID;
```

Which gives the following result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks....I got some sleep and went back to the drawing board.

Decided to reformat the output of my optimizer for each extrusion so that the cuts are listed as a string separated by semicolons. It made it much easier to group and count duplicates. I can just split up the cuts by semicolon when I retrieve the data.

```
    group_id | qty |        Cuts                
       1       27     138.18750;138.18750;
       2       22     67.56250;67.56250;67.56250;67.56250;
       3       15     89.31250;89.31250;89.31250;
       4       15     88.93750;88.93750;88.93750;
```